# IDE Tool for showing who wrote which line of code attached to a git repository?

Tags: git, ide

I work in small groups regularly and have to communicate needs and mistakes to developers.

Is there a tool or way to see who wrote what line of code.
I'm using Php storm, but Id be open to another standalone.

I need to see who wrote what piece of code so I can then send change requests to that user.

Comment: RMB on the left of the code (between line numbers and the actual editor) -> annotate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know phpstorm, but netbeans has the show annotation feature, based on git blame command:

1. Main menu "Team->Show Annotations" OR
2. "Git->Show Annotations" in the context menu of a file in the project/files view

It will show you each line with the commiter's username.

BTW, you can also "git blame" any file for the same result.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume PHP Storm uses the same thing as Intellij Idea - click RMB on the area between line numbers and the editor:

[image]

This should give you a per-line list of people responsible for changes - as per `git blame` (or, in my company, people with wrong formatter settings)